# Como desmarcar uma CheckBox ao marcar a outra?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Estou trabalhando com duas `CheckBox` onde preciso que ao marcar uma, a outra se desmarque automaticamente e vice-versa.

Tentei o seguinte, mas sem sucesso:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkEspaço1" runat="server" Text="Checkbox 1"/>
<br />
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkEspaço2" runat="server" Text="Chekbox 2"/>

Private Sub chkEspaço1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkEspaço1.CheckedChanged

        Dim bChkEspaço1 = chkEspaço1
        Dim bChkEspaço2 = chkEspaço2

        If bChkEspaço1.Checked = True Then
            bChkEspaço2.Checked = False
        End If


End Sub

Private Sub chkEspaço2_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkEspaço2.CheckedChanged

        Dim bChkEspaço1 = chkEspaço1
        Dim bChkEspaço2 = chkEspaço2

        If bChkEspaço2.Checked = True Then
            bChkEspaço1.Checked = False
        End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Deveria usar um _radio button_ para esse tipo de comportamento...

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa incluir a tag `autopostback` na `CheckBox` para que seja chamado o evento server-side

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkEspaço1" autopostback="true" runat="server" Text="Checkbox 1"/>
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkEspaço2" autopostback="true" runat="server" Text="Chekbox 2"/>
```